# Accessing the class attribute in jQuery - Key, value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I am struggling with fetching the class of my divs, that are planned to become tabs on a basic asp.net website. I wish to do this with jQuery as that would allow me more control for dynamic functions later. However, when I try to fetch the value of the certain "selectedTab", I just get "undefined".
My question is how I can store the relevant class together with the name for that object (which I believe I have got right in my code), and then retrieve it.

This is the relevant parts of my very simple html:

```
<div id="t1" class="tabs"></div>
<div id="t2" class="tabs"></div>
<div id="t3" class="selectedTab"></div>
<p></p>
```

And my jQuery:

```
var tabMatchList = [{
    "tab1": "tabs"
}, {
    "tab2": "tabs"
}, {
    "tab3": "selectedTab"
}];
$.each(tabMatchList, function (i, val) {
    if ($("#t3").attr("class") == val[0]) {
        $("p").append(i + " was the tab searched for");
    } else {
        $("p").append(i + " was not the tab searched for." + val[0]);
    }
});
```

All help and advice is very welcome.

Comment: `selectedTab` or `selectedTabs`? Also I assume you are aware that `tab1` and `tab2` will both match `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: I am aware that it will match both `t1` and `t2`. That is my intention. As for the `selectedTabs` that was a typo as I wrote in the code here :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.attr("class")` will return the class name **without** the `.`, so you need to remove that from your array:

Also, your array has the class `selectedTab`, but in your HTML the class is `selectedTabs`. Make sure they match.

That aside, your code won't work as is:

Firstly, we need to name the properties in your array of objects:

```
var tabMatchList = [{
    tabName: "tab1", tabClass: "tabs"
    }, {
    tabName: "tab2", tabClass: "tabs"
    }, {
    tabName: "tab3", tabClass: "selectedTab"
}];
```

Then we can do the following:

```
$.each(tabMatchList, function (i, val) {
    if ($("#t3").attr("class") == val.tabClass) {
        $("p").append(" " + val.tabName + " was the tab searched for ");
    } else {
        $("p").append(" " + val.tabName + " was not the tab searched for.");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ocycjua/1/)

Comment: This still does not work. I have added a jFiddle with the suggested changes here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vrcp78e8/)

Comment: @ChristianS Check my updated answer I've provided a demo, there were numerous other issues with your code so I have rewritten it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#t1,#t2,#t3').each(function(i){
    if($(this).attr('class') == 'selectedTab' ){
       $("p").append(i + " was the tab searched for <br/>"); 
    }else{
         $("p").append(i + " was not the tab searched for." + $(this).attr('class') + "<br/>");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jd2a1czk/)